# Adding wordsAPI library to solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to add the wordsAPI to my solution. Here are the instructions they give on the site:
[WordsAPI REST API documentation](http://restunited.com/releases/424223873313015558/wrappers)

Open or create a C# application using your favorite IDE
**Done**

Add the folder WordsAPI-csharp to the project's "lib" folder **I don't have a "lib" folder**

Add System.Web and WordsAPI-csharp/bin/Newtonsoft.Json.dll to the project's "References"**I have the Newtonsoft.Json.dll in a using statement. This is the only thing I actually got into my solution**

**They're saying this is what the using statements should look like**

using System.Web;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using Com.Wordsapi.Www.WordsAPI.Api;

using Com.Wordsapi.Www.WordsAPI.Model;

**I can't add the Com.Wordsapi... using statemtents for some reason. No matter where I put the folder**

I've tried putting it in the solution folder, the solution itself at project and solution level. I've also tried putting it in debug, bin...you name it. Visual Studio 2015 does not see it. I've tried contacting support for the api, but got no response.

Any help getting this into my solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: WordsAPI-csharp is present in the references?

Comment: WordsAPI-csharp is a folder with multiple files needed. Visual studio will only let me import file level references. So no, I can't add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the WordsApi .dll's you have to build them. These steps loosely follow the guide I found [here](http://restunited.com/docs/6vc24wq3ojpq#example_code)

1. Paste wget link ([currently this](http://files1.restunited.com/libraries/www_wordsapi_com_022946/beta/0/1/0/sw/WordsAPI-beta-0.1.0-csharp.tar.gz)) into your browser and download
2. Extract `WordsAPI-csharp` to solutions packages folder (I used winrar)
3. Open a command prompt and navigate to `WordsAPI-csharp` folder
4. Run `compile.bat`
5. Back in visual studio Right-Click references in your Project and select "Add References..."
6. Select Browse at the bottom of the left pane and then click Browse... at the bottom
7. Navigate to `...\WordsAPI-csharp\bin\ and add` Com.Wordsapi.Www.WordsAPI.dll` and other .dll's if you encounter dependency issues with NuGet